# Connect multiple clients to a websocket server braodcasting data

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am creating a websocket server where you are supposed to be able to connect with multiple clients. When a client connects it will recieve some information once, and when recieved it will continue to listen to the braodcasted data. The server would be able to "broadcast" data simultaneously to all clients, but can't seem to figure out how to continously update the data, when listening for new connected clients.

I have tried using asynchio's create task, and using an infinite while loop. Everything works perfectly when the first client tries to connect. But the problem arises when the second client tries to connect, or the first one refreshes the connection. Its is stuck in the while loop and have stopped listening to new connections

Also tried to use threading on the result handler.

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect(websocket, path):
    # Sendt only once
    await websocket.send(some_json_data))

async def report(websocket, path):
    # Should be sendt continously to all connected clients
    while True:
        await websocket.send(braodcast_data)

async def task_handler(websocket, path):
    await self.connect(websocket, path)
    await self.report(websocket, path)

start_server = websockets.serve(task_handler, 'localhost', 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

As stated before the I understand that this will get stuck in the while loop, but i can't seem to find any other solution to the problem.

Comment: Look into asynchronous web sockets